# Animating the active item background in a nav fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, append, offset

I have the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">largerWord</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

The items have transparent background except the active class, that has a blue color.

The idea is that when user clicks (not the active) instead of switching the backgrounds i want to move the background, you can see the result almost done here, but it fails the first click (see end of question for error log):

http://jsfiddle.net/FeV55/26/

What i do is to dynamically create a lower z-index `<li>` and animate the left according the (clicked) item offset and the width according the (clicked) item width

The jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul li a').not('.active').click(function(){
        /*caching*/       
        var activa = $('li.active');
        var bg = $('li.back');;
        var list = $(this).closest('ul');
        /*when it's first click the background item doesnt exist*/
        if(bg.length>0 == false){
            list.append('<li class="back"></li>');
        }
        var width = $(this).outerWidth(true);
        var leftUL = list.offset().left;
        var leftThis = $(this).offset().left;
        var left  = leftThis - leftUL;
        /*Remove class to previous active*/
        activa.removeClass('active');
        /*Cancel background even if parent is active*/
        $(this).addClass('noBg');
        /*Update active class*/
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        /*Move the background to its offset*/
        bg.animate({'left':left,'width':width});

        /*logs*/
        $('#oUl').text(leftUL);
        $('#ocl').text($(this).offset().left);
        $('#odf').text(left);
        $('#obg').text(bg.offset().left);
    });
});
```

But it fails on first click, firebug logs:

```
bg.offset() is null
[Parar en este error]   

$('#obg').text(bg.offset().left);
```

Question is why? the item should exist by then in any case..

Comment: I don't see any error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to select the element you've assigned to `bg` after you create it:

```
 var bg = $('li.back');

 if (bg.length == 0) {
   list.append('<li class="back"></li>');
   bg = $('li.back');
 }
```

Even better, create the element *into* `bg`:

```
 if (bg.length == 0) {
   bg = $('<li class="back"></li>');
   list.append(bg);
 }
```

Comment: second option wont work because bg was being used later as a selector... but first does, thanks!